# Choosing the right salt to pseudo-anonymize data and be GDPR compliant

Tags: hash, salt, gdpr, pii

In my company, numeric user IDs are considered PIIs and therefore need to be pseudo-anonymized to be GDPR compliant.

To do so, we populate a lookup table where to each ID is assigned a monotonically decreasing `gdpr_ID`. Then when users are inactive or request to be deleted, we simply update the ID column by using the `gdpr_ID` value, making it impossible to know that `gdpr_ID` was originally linked to a specific ID.

The downside of this approach is that we have different tables where these IDs appear and we need to anonymize these records, but this lookup table is getting bigger and bigger, making our ETL pipelines increasingly slower.

The solution we were thinking about was to use a hashing function, but since IDs are just numbers we need to attach a salt. How can we generate this salt in such a way that `salt(ID)` always returns the same value, without having to create/use lookup tables and, at the same time, not being able to reconstruct it?

Comment: Isn't that basically saying that you want `salt(ID)` both deterministic (always returns the same value) and non-deterministic (nobody can check if it returns a specific output given a specific input) at the same time? That's impossible. If you have zillions of users you could make such brute forcing by checking all inputs infeasible if the function is slow enough and the range of possible inputs large enough though.

Comment: Can you `salt(ID + secretvalue)`? Any consumer of the data warehouse would not be able to reverse the ID without that secret value.

Comment: Since you are not interested in  the actual id, nor in correlating it with past transactions why keep it.  Why not just an auto-increment field

Answer (score 0):

you could generate salt by using UUID from string. but i believe this is effectively same as hashing.

```
String inputStr = "12345";

UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(inputStr);
UUID uuid2 = UUID.fromString(inputStr);
UUID uuid3 = UUID.fromString(inputStr);

assertEquals(uuid, uuid2);
assertEquals(uuid, uuid3);
```